# Adding Bin/Lot/Serial item to Acumatica shipment lines

Tags: erp, acumatica

Adding Bin/Lot/Serial item to Acumatica shipment lines
I are able to create an Acumatica shipment through Web Services, but getting an issue in adding Bin/Lot Number for each line in the grid.  If I have only one document detail line in shipment, it is working fine, but when there is more than one line in document details, the code does not seem to be working.  Please find below the Acumatica code that I am using to achieve this.

```
SO302000Content soShipcontent = content.SO302000GetSchema();
List<Command> scmds = new List<Command>();
List<LineDetails> splits = new List<LineDetails>();
CreateShipmentHeader(soShipcontent, hparams, ref scmds, Ordernumber);
var shipmentresults = content.SO302000Submit(scmds.ToArray());
if (shipmentresults != null && shipmentresults.Length > 0)
{
int linen = 0;
List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
foreach (var row in shipmentresults)
{                           
SO302000Content c = (SO302000Content)row;
cmds.Add(new Value { Value = linen.ToString(), LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.AddSalesOrder.ServiceCommands.RowNumber });
cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "True", LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.AddSalesOrder.Selected, Commit = true });
LineDetails ld = details.Find(x => x.InventoryId == c.AddSalesOrder.InventoryID.Value.ToString().Trim());
if (ld != null)
{
LineDetails splitno = new LineDetails();
splitno.InventoryId = ld.InventoryId;
splitno.Location = ld.Location;
splitno.LotNo = ld.LotNo;
splitno.Quantity = c.AddSalesOrder.Quantity.Value.ToString().Trim();
splitno.LineNumber = (linen).ToString();
splits.Add(splitno);
} 
linen++;
}

cmds.Add(soShipcontent.Actions.AddSO);
content.SO302000Submit(cmds.ToArray());

foreach (LineDetails s in splits)
{
List<Command> cmdsplit = new List<Command>();
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.LineNumber, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.ServiceCommands.RowNumber });
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.InventoryId, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.InventoryID, Commit = true });
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.Location, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.Location, Commit = true });
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.LotNo, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.LotSerialNbr });
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.Quantity, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.Quantity });                            
content.SO302000Submit(cmdsplit.ToArray());                         
}                      
}

List<Command> cmds1 = new List<Command>();
string shipmentnbr = string.Empty;
cmds1.Add(soShipcontent.Actions.Save);
cmds1.Add(soShipcontent.ShipmentSummary.ShipmentNbr);
content.SO302000Submit(cmds1.ToArray());
```

I have tried below code also:

```
cmds.Add(soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.Location, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.Location});
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.LotNo, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.LotSerialNbr });
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.Quantity, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.Quantity, Commit = true });
cmdsplit.Add(new Value { Value = s.InventoryId, LinkedCommand = soShipcontent.BinLotSerialNumbers.InventoryID });
cmdsplit.Add(new Key { Value = "='" + s.InventoryId + "'", FieldName = soShipcontent.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.FieldName, ObjectName = soShipcontent.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.ObjectName });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i'm not really following your code but i would say that acumatica an assign SN automatically depends on the item settings. Otherwise you can manually assign SN.

The most simplest example is when you have qty = 1 on the detail level, see code below

```
            Content[] result = context.Submit(
            new Command[]
            {
                new Value { Value = "000200", LinkedCommand = SO302000.ShipmentSummary.ShipmentNbr, Commit = true },

                //navigate to line
                new Key
                {
                    ObjectName = SO302000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.ObjectName,
                    FieldName = SO302000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.FieldName,
                    Value = "='INCLUTA009'"
                },

                new Value { Value = "20SP0610", LinkedCommand = SO302000.DocumentDetails.LotSerialNbr, Commit = true },

                SO302000.Actions.Save
            }
        );
```